# Proprietary Haskell Library

Tags: haskell, shared-libraries, licensing, obfuscation, software-distribution

I am somewhat new to Haskell, been using it for a few months now for side projects.  I'd like to write a Haskell interface to a C library.  All code will be proprietary, not open source.  So my question is, what if I end up distributing this to a customer and don't want to provide the source code, but rather something like a shared library.  In C I can build the code for the target platform and provide header files.  Can I do something similar in Haskell?

Comment: You can certainly provide a `build`t cabal project without the source files, that would do. But why bother hiding the source of the Haskell interface? When the C library is closed-source anyway, there's not much interesting anybody can do with the h2c sources alone.

Comment: It's a little harder to do this with Haskell than C because the end-user will need to use exactly the same versions of every library your package is built against, with some installation flags the same, and the same GHC.  If you can get by with @leftaroundabout's suggestion, do so.  Otherwise, perhaps you could tar up the ghc database directory and distribute that (or set it up via nix or some other package manager)?  Of course you'd also need to check the licenses of every other package you include if you do this.

Comment: I suppose I could see a scenario where I would have some feature in Haskell that isn't part of the library and if that were the case, I'd keep it private.  How does GHC know what functions are in a module without the source code?  I compiled my own module and tried loading it into GHCI and I can't import it.

Comment: Re @John L's comment. I wonder if you can exploit stack to make this simpler since ghc and each package versions are known and stable. You'd just need to agree a resolver with your customer.