# Distribute proprietary/closed source Haskell lib using STG

Tags: haskell, compatibility, ghc, bytecode, software-distribution

Having read questions such as [Proprietary Haskell Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454451/proprietary-haskell-library) and considering GHC completely lacks binary compatibility between even minor versions, I'm wondering would it be possible to use STG (or Core or similar) as a means to distribute obfuscated (i.e. "almost binary") proprietary libraries that can then be compiled to machine code at the final stage?

I'm aware STG was not designed for this, but the idea seems neat in a way.

Comment: As I recall, GHC doesn't have any way to read those intermediate languages back in from a file. And they aren't entirely stable either, e.g. Core is set to change big in 8.0.

Comment: aha; but "not entirely stable" seems much better that "entirely not stable" :)